# openright option for \part and not for \chapter

Tags: chapters, books, parts

I need in a book class document to open the `\part` in an odd page. The option `\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}` is very convenient.

Unfortunately, I want to keep my `\chapter` opening on any pages.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}
\begin{document}
\part{1st part begin in an odd page, perfect}
\chapter{chapter begin in an odd page and not on anypage}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix that? Declaring

```
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse
\chapter{Chapter begin in any page}
\@openrighttrue\makeatother
```

for each chapter is not a good solution for me... Same for the reverse method if I should redefine `openright` on each part.

Thanks for your help !

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Your English seems quite clear:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simplest, assuming you don't have many parts is to use `openany` and start each part with

```
\cleardoublepage
\part
```

if you do not want the `\cleardoublepage` to be explicit then just use `\part` and put

```
\let\oldpart\part
\def\part{\cleardoublepage\oldpart}
```

in the preamble of your document

Comment: The first solution is not exactly what i was looking for. The second one works perfectly and fits exactly with what i wanted !
Thanks a lot !